# How to serialize C# object in binary format

Tags: c#

I have this code in Java, that serialize some object in binary format.

```
void save(String name) {
   try {
       FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(name);
       ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
       os.writeObject(this);
       os.close();
       }
   catch (Exception ex) {
   }
}
```

I need to do this in C#, how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the _trouble_ you get exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save some object in binary format, you can use **BinaryFormatter** class. But this class require that your class that you want to serialize, must be decorated with **Serializable** attribute.

So the class Person below, is an example how to do that.

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public void Save(string filePath)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
    }


    public static Person ReadFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            return (Person)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

And you can use like that:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Person { Name = "Alberto Monteiro", Age = 25 };
        p.Save("person.bin");

        var person = Person.ReadFromFile("person.bin");
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
    }
}
```